# Graphic Novel, early 90s, multiple fantasy/scifi stories

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, comics, young-adult

I've been trying to identify an English language graphic novel I read in the early 90s, it was in the YA section of the local library, so the content wasn't too 'Heavy Metal'.

The first story involved the male protagonist in some sort of arid/hilly environment fighting a flying beast-man (who had wings on his back), then meeting up with a female temptress who took him back to her castle, lured him to bed, then pulled a dagger out from under her pillow with the aim of doing him in. Protagonist escaped and the beast-man might have arrived on the scene again.

The second story diverged completely, with a pair of scuba divers swimming too close to the propeller of a large boat, then having to get away. There were further stories past this, but I don't recall any details of them.

The art style was fairly normal for comics of the time.